# datastax driver connection = apache ignite and cassandra(you may want to increase the driver number of per-host connections)

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, ignite, datastax-java-driver

Components: apache ignite + apache cassandra. Use defaut datastax driver.
After doing several operation(about 3-5 billions entities put to cache) we get a situation when datastax driver always reconnects to cassandra from ignite.

```
2017-02-16 13:29:21.287  INFO 160487 --- [ sys-#441%null%] m.r.t.d.c.m.p.c.c.p.RetryPolicyImpl      :  init cluster
2017-02-16 13:29:21.288  INFO 160487 --- [ sys-#441%null%] com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster         : New Cassandra host <our host> added
2017-02-16 13:29:21.307  INFO 160487 --- [ sys-#441%null%] m.r.t.d.c.m.p.c.c.p.RetryPolicyImpl      :  close cluster
2017-02-16 13:29:23.516  INFO 160487 --- [ sys-#441%null%] com.datastax.driver.core.ClockFactory    : Using native clock to generate timestamps.
2017-02-16 13:29:23.537  INFO 160487 --- [ sys-#441%null%] c.d.d.c.p.DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy        : Using data-center name 'datacenter1' for DCAw
```

And this process is endless and it can be interrupted by server restarted.

Infrastructure :
1 server ignite - ~Xmx30g and 8 cores. 
25 clients ignites ~Xmx1g and 8 cores.
1 node cassandra.
Batch size(entities which will be put to cache and then cassandra) is about 1-2M.

Config datasource =>

```
 public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
        dataSource.setUser(login);
        dataSource.setPassword(pass);
        dataSource.setPort(port);
        dataSource.setContactPoints(host);
        dataSource.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
        dataSource.setFetchSize(10_000);
        dataSource.setReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(1000));
        dataSource.setLoadBalancingPolicy(DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.builder().withUsedHostsPerRemoteDc(0).build());
        dataSource.setSocketOptions(new SocketOptions().setReadTimeoutMillis(100_000).setConnectTimeoutMillis(100_00));
        return dataSource;
    }
```

config cache =>

```
 CacheConfiguration<KeyIgnite, Long> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<>();
        cfg
                .setName(area)
                .setRebalanceMode(CacheRebalanceMode.SYNC)
                .setStartSize(1_000_000)
                .setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC)
                .setIndexedTypes(KeyIgnite.class, Long.class)
                .setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED)
                .setBackups(0);

        if (!clientMode) {

            CassandraCacheStoreFactory<KeyIgnite, Long> csFactory = new CassandraCacheStoreFactory<>();
            csFactory.setDataSource(ds);
            csFactory.setPersistenceSettings(kv);

//            CassandraCacheStoreFactoryDwh<KeyIgnite, Long> csFactory = new CassandraCacheStoreFactoryDwh<>(ds, kv,params);

            cfg
                    .setCacheStoreFactory(csFactory)
                    .setReadThrough(true)
                    .setWriteThrough(true);
        }

        cfg.setExpiryPolicyFactory(TouchedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(new Duration(TimeUnit.DAYS, 5)));
        return cfg;
```

ignite config =>:

```
   TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder finder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
        finder.setAddresses(adresses);

        return Ignition.start(
                new IgniteConfiguration()
                        .setClientMode(clientMode)
                        .setDiscoverySpi(new TcpDiscoverySpi().setIpFinder(finder).setNetworkTimeout(10000))
                        .setFailureDetectionTimeout(50000)
                        .setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(false)
                        .setLoadBalancingSpi(new RoundRobinLoadBalancingSpi())

        );
```

When we have done several iteration of putting items to cache we have gotten this case.

after including debug level i have gotten this record:

```
2017-02-17 17:48:41.570 DEBUG 24816 --- [ sys-#184%null%] com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler  : [1071994376-1] Error querying ds-inmemorydb-02t/10.216.28.34:9042 : com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timeout while trying to acquire available connection (you may want to increase the driver number of per-host connections)
```

Comment: This situation is happened when we starts over 10 client nods in parallel.

Comment: Boris, can you please add threaddumps of the nodes you get "timeout" message at? You should also find out what other connections on those nodes are busy with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timeout increase on the driver helped